# Selenium en servidor Ubuntu no carga el contenido dinámico de la página web

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, vps, ubuntu-server

Tengo un programa de Python cuyo objetivo es abrir y cargar una página web dinámica. Para ello, el script es el siguiente

```
url="https://www.bet365.es"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

#This for arguments above, I've tried with and without them. No difference

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
    
browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                          "source": """
                            Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                              get: () => undefined
                            })
                          """
                        })
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
                            {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})
    
browser.get(url)
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//div[contains(@class,"-WebConsoleModule ")]')))
print('Browser Bet365 abierto')
```

Para ejecutarlo en la terminal de Ubuntu `xvfb-run -a python3 stest.py start`.

Haciendo esto, a veces consigo que se cargue, como prueba la imagen siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo normal sin embargo es que el script de error al buscar el xpath. Imprimiendo el page-source he visto que lo que hay cargado es lo mismo que si se cargara la página en un navegador normal, y se diera a Ctrl+U. Es decir, selenium no está cargando el contenido dinámico de la web.

- Si no pongo el prefijo `xvfb-run` el chromedriver no se abre (DevPortActiveTools file doesn't exists)
- Los 4 argumentos pasados como `.add_argument` no suponen diferencia alguna. Ha cargado con y sin ellos, y ha dejado de cargar con y sin ellos.
- Los argumentos de `.add_experimental_option` y los de `execute` son necesarios porque Bet365 si no detecta que es un navegador automatizado y no te muestra el contenido.

Necesito entender por qué no siempre la ejecución es exitosa, y qué cambiar para que selenium y chromedriver se comporten como en remoto y carguen todo el contenido, incluido el dinámico, el 100% de las veces.